# Any disadvantage of android:onClick attribute usage?

Tags: android

What is of these ways is better for onClick's methods implementation: 
- Using android:onClick attribute in xml
- Implementing and defining onClickListener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my personal opinion, defining implementing and defining the `OnClickListener` is much better. The main reason is that it's easier for others to understand how the code works.

When you are reading the code of an Android app you will be reading the .java files (90% of the time) to understand how it works; you will ignore most of the XML layouts which does not tell you how the app actually works or what is its purpose.

Thus, if you use the `android:onClick` attribute, you will force others (and yourself) to look at both sides: XML layouts and Java source to understand the flow and intention of your app, which is not nice.

Notice that it's a matter of readability; technically speaking there should not be any difference of performance.

Comment: I think naming conventions can overcome much of that. If I see a method named `buttonFrozz_onClick(View)`, and there’s also a `buttonFrozz` somewhere, I would have no problem connecting the two. More declarative, less imperative.

Comment: Yeah... that's a good point. But, useful if you come from C# for example; however on the Java land, and more specifically on the Android land, you won't see those conventions (I'm talking about the way the Android core is written).

Comment: `android:onClick` has a major advantage in addition to being less code - it's part of a layout resource. The resource is selected at runtime depending on the current configuration of the device. Some parts of your UI might use different variants of the same layout depending on whether the device is in landscape/portrait mode, has a different screen size, etc. In a situation like this you can use `onClick` attributes on each element to wire things up appropriately rather than a lot of code to determine what elements are present at runtime.

Comment: @adamp +1. Good reason to use `android:onClick`

Answer (score 4):

It is explained better on following  link using **android:onClick is better than onClickListener**, is it is difficult for other to understand but is good but it has several advantages.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use onClick in your XML, it makes it easier for your designers and UI people, if you put it in your Code it makes it "easier" for your programmers who know it's in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use android:onClick because it makes the java code look more clean to me rather than having a bunch of switch statements and findViewById calls.  However, if you forget to implement the function for android:onClick then it will cause a forceclose when the view is touched.

Answer (score 0):

If your minSdkVersion is 4 (1.6) or higher, use android:onClick.  It will keep your code cleaner and is easy to read.  If your minSdkVersion is less than 4 (e.g., 3 which is 1.5), do *not* use the onClick attribute because it will be ignored.

The onClick attribute uses reflection to create an OnClickListener that is set on the View and uses reflection to invoke your method.  For the vast majority of apps, that is fine and will never be an issue, but it's worth considering for processor-intensive apps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML onClick attribute is much tidier. However as already pointed out it lacks the visibility of showing where the onClick is declared. I have created an annotation that improves the visibility of XML declared onclicks, so when scannign through your code you have a better understanding of what is going on.

Check it out here:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/using-annotations-for-android-xml-onclick-visibility/

An example:

```
 @FromXML
 public void onSomeXmlButtonClick(View button){

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Does this explanation of onclick event (HTML/ASP) apply somehow to the android world?

http://spicr.net/jnit/?p=13